# How to duplicate form using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form that I need to duplicate. I want to create a different form for every person on my team (30+ people).

I've looked into [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) and I could not find a method that duplicates the form.

This is what I want to do:

```
var template_form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var new_form = template_form.a_method_that_duplicates_the_form(); // Could not find this method
var new_form_id = new_form.getId();
... //and so on...
```

Is there any way to duplicate forms using Google App Script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Form Service** can only create, access, and modify **Google Forms**. In order to duplicate Forms, you have to use the **Drive Service**.

Here I created a code that duplicates a Form, change its Title and save it to a specific location in Drive:

```
function duplicateForm() {
  var templateformId = 'template form id here';
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("destination folder id");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(templateformId).makeCopy("file name", destFolder);
  var fileId = file.getId()
}
```

**Template Form:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)
- [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
- [File.makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination)